# Multibyte character display in Java console

Tags: java, utf-8, multibyte, tamil

I have some text to be printed in Tamil. How can I get it printed in Tamil on Java console. I'm testing a piece of code and for debugging I require to see the text being printed.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "வீடிவீடிவீடிவீடிவீடி";
    System.out.println("String is : "+str);
 }
```

Shows output in java console as

```
String is : ?????????????
```

Comment: Add your codes and share where  your problems are ?

Comment: please refer edits

Comment: Your Java code. Please include a [MCVE]. Also which console are you using?

Comment: Edited code. Actually I am running an applet file. Java console enabled at system level (i.e in Java Control Panel). I want to c tamil text in this console.

Answer (score 1):

- **First Solution**

I'm not sure but you can use open tamil jar for it.

[see this](https://ezhillang.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/open-tamil-java-usage/) might help you.

- **Second Solution**

Got to project Properties-> Resource->change the Radio button to "Other"-> and select "UTF-8" from drop down.

[image: See the screen shot.]

In my eclipse its working.
[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks sir, actually I am running an applet file. Java console enabled at system level (i.e in Java Control Panel). I want to c tamil text in this console.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Eclipse Ide change bottom configurations and try.

Window > Preferences > General > Content Types, set UTF-8 as the default encoding for all content types.
Window > Preferences > General > Workspace, set "Text file encoding" to "Other : UTF-8".

Comment: Thanks sir, actually I am running an applet file. Java console enabled at system level (i.e in Java Control Panel). I want to see tamil text in this console