# my jar application (javax.mail) only works in netbeans

Tags: java, classpath, jakarta-mail

I use for sending mail **javax.mail.jar** .
My application sends mail in Arabic **only in netbeans**, but exucutable jar sends mail but caractaires are like that **????????**

I add the jar as follows (see image)

someone has an idea and thank you very much
[image: classpath]

Comment: have you check the encoding of class?

Comment: please check my answer to set encoding.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132530/multibyte-character-display-in-java-console/37132827#37132827